# facebook realtitme update in android returns null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to get realtime_update when user's friendlist changes and am trying to subscribe to `friends` object .I have the code below where I added `params.putString("access_token", "12|wewee");` because I used to get  `{This method must be called with an app access_token.}, isFromCache:false}` .Now I get the response as displayed below.I would like to get realtime subscription .How do I make it work? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("object", "user");
params.putString("access_token", "12|wewee");
params.putString("callback_url", "http://example.com/callback/update.php");
params.putString("fields", "friends");
params.putString("verify_token", "1234");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/12345/subscriptions",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Note: `session =fb.getsession();`

added param to get app_access_tokem:

```
params.putString("access_token", "12|wewee");
```

and I get this response :

```
  {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":null}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

Comment: pls log the complete `GraphObject` and print here

Comment: `{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":null}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}` This is all I get in log

Comment: It has a Graph Object, you have to log that

Comment: This is all the response I get in logcat.Can you be more specific to what in logcat are you looking for ?Also you can write the code to the above I will paste the updated code you write and can display updated log details.Do  you want me to convert graphobject.tostring() ?

Comment: Yes. the content of : `GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();`

Comment: `GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":null}}` after `GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
             Log.w("graphObject",graphObject.toString());`